range join optimization in databricks
I have a pyspark join
dfnew = dfnew.join(df, on=((f.col('id1')==f.col('id2')))&(f.col('time').between(f.col("StartTime"), f.col("endTime")))&(f.col('tag1')==f.col('tag2')),    how="inner")

When I run this query, databricks generates message stating to enable range join to improve the performance.
So I changed the code like the below
dfnew = dfnew.join(df.hint("range_join", 60*60), on=((f.col('id1')==f.col('id2')))&(f.col('time').between(f.col("StartTime"), f.col("endTime")))&(f.col('tag1')==f.col('tag2')),    how="inner")

I used df.hint("range_join", 60*60) because I know I am extracting close to 1 hour of data and the time is in timestamp format. The documentation is not particularly clear to me.
Is this the correct way to enable range join optimization?

Where did you find the input value range_join? I checked the Spark docs and can't find it. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-hints.html#hints

Also, if you know the range of data that you need in df, why don't apply filtering on your df before joining? You might be able to leverage broadcast join after filtering

never knew such a thing existed - Doc link for reference.
